# Changing MAC address causes to stop telnet in VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

I need to change dynamically MAC address in VxWorks 7.
MAC address has been correctly changed.
After changing the MAC address, I can not use telnet and ping to the interface.

Using VxWorks 7, Arm, dcc.

```
// in usrAppInit()
struct ifreq ifr;
int s;
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,"eth0",5);
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[0] = 0x01;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[1] = 0x02;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[2] = 0x03;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[3] = 0x04;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[4] = 0x05;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[5] = 0x06;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
ioctl(s, SIOCSIFLLADDR, &ifr); // eth0 mac address changed to 01:02:03:04:05:06
close(s);
```

After changing MAC address,
"ping" and "telnet" can not reach to that interface from PC.
"arp" command displays new MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JaeMann Yeh, this worked for me:

```
ifconfig ("qfec0 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifconfig to change the MAC address in your c file. For example,

```
ipcom_run_cmd("ifconfig qfec0 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55");
```

I have tested it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the least significant bit in byte 0. That indicates it's a multicast address, don't set your mac address to a multicast address.

Set it to something else , e.g.

```
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data[0] = 0x00;
```